# unmount error on linux installation

Tags: linux, boot, operating-systems, manjaro

I have an Asus GL503GE laptop
{128gb M.2 ssd C:drive with windows 10}
{500gb sata ssd D:drive}

I tried installing Manjaro as well as popOS.
during the install boot from usb stick I always get some unmount error and the installation fails.

**On pop OS :
[FAILED] Failed unmounting cdrom.mount.**

**On manjaro:
[FAILED] Failed unmounting Temporary /etc/pacman.d/gnupg directory
[FAILED] Failed unmounting /run/miso/cowspace**

I have secure boot as well as fastboot off in BIOS. I tried disconnecting the drives. I also tried 3 diff downloads of the same iso using RUFUS.(3 times popOS and 3 times manjaro). RUFUS is set to GPT partition and UEFI.

Please help

Comment: Check if there is any unwanted entry in `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: idk what happened but suddenly pop OS and mint iso's started working...will try manjaro later and update